# How to upload Bitmap to server without converting to String using volley?

Tags: php, android, kotlin, android-volley

I am uploading several bitmaps of Images to the server using Volley Library. I also need to receive the image file in PHP as `$_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]`.

I checked a few solutions which utilize bitmap to string method which doesn't provide good results when the bitmap size is Big. I got a few solutions with volley multi parts as well but they are not well explained and don't understand how to write it in Kotlin.

I expect to store the image bitmap in the desired folder with only Volley library.